# Performing external API calls in the background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm calling a paging API to get a bunch of data. This can mean up to 200 calls, one after the other, to get all of the data. I'm using Typhoeus to run 5 concurrent calls and performance is pretty good. On a slower network though it's awful.

Ideally I would like to have these requests run in the background while showing some progress indicator (even just a simple spinner) allowing the user to continue to browse the site until the jobs are completed (or I will save after each request completes slowly making the data visible to the user).

I can't find a way to do this. I currently have a button on the page that calls a method in the controller that starts the requests. Am I doing this the wrong way? How can I run these requests without blocking the UI.

Comment: What you want is Active Job -> https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

Comment: For the progress indicator: You have to associate a model with this request. It can be the object you are trying to process itself or create a "background request model". 
Give it a state variable. In your controller set the state to in progress. In your job you can set the state to finish.
In your frontend remember the request id and do a poll every X seconds to see if its finished.

Comment: Websockets are IMO a "cleaner" way than polling and better performance too

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question isn't asked well. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages. Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Comment: @SimonFranzen thanks for pointing out ActiveJob. I've moved my API request code into one and it's improved things a lot.

Comment: @maxpleaner thanks for the tip on web sockets. I'm setting up ActionCable at the moment and it looks like what I need.